# Aem Event on View Properties in Touch UI

Tags: aem

I have a custom multifield JS where I am populating it on dialog ready event.
The same multifield is used in Page Properties field also.

In touch UI when we are viewing the properties of page from sites my custom code doesn't kick in as it's not a dialog.

Can any body help in knowing what is the even when we click on view properties?

Comment: To improve the response you get from your questions, consider doing such things as posting a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work), making your question clear in the title ,[adding necessary tags](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)... and [heading on over to the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info

Answer (score 3):

Try the event `foundation-contentloaded` this event might be triggered twice for page properties, so please protect your code against that by making sure it only runs once.

Answer (score 0):

View Properties opens the page in full view instead of a dialog or modal. For touch UI the events are [jQuery based events](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

You can use [document ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) event handler for full page

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Handle stuff here
});
```