# AEM: dialog-ready event not firing in ipad

Tags: ipad, aem

I have a multi-field in AEM whose field values are populated on the event "dialog-ready". This is working fine in desktop. But in ipad, the cq-dialog is not opening as a dialog. It opens as a page in full screen mode. Thus the dialog-ready event is not firing and I get a empty field values.

Comment: can you hook the device to a mac, switch to developer mode and see if you are seeing any console errors?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274570/aem-event-on-view-properties-in-touch-ui. This is similar issue. `dialog-ready` is not fired in full page dialog view.

Answer (score 1):

Please try `foundation-contentloaded` event.